# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. Python

Tags: python, python-requests

So, I have this piece of code:

```
grade = session.get('https://api-ege.interneturok.ru/api/v2/journal/pages?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvYXBpLXBzcC5pbnRlcm5ldHVyb2sucnVcL2FwaVwvdjJcL3Rva2VucyIsImlhdCI6MTY2NDk5MzQ0NiwiZXhwIjoxNjY0OTk3MDQ2LCJuYmYiOjE2NjQ5OTM0NDYsImp0aSI6IjE3OUpMYmhIb3ByYnZOdjIiLCJzdWIiOjI5MTY0NDIsInBydiI6IjIzYmQ1Yzg5NDlmNjAwYWRiMzllNzAxYzQwMDg3MmRiN2E1OTc2ZjcifQ.RfPkDzTOKawwAQTp_4v6XU-hQgOazmFb7rkv80naT1w')
```

It gives me this response:

```
'{"pages":[{"id":7684904,"school":true,"grade":8}]}'
```

Then I have this piece of code, that should give me the page I need:

```
j = session.get('https://interneturok.ru/school/student-journal/school/' + json.loads(grade.content)['pages']['grade'])
```

But I get this:

```
j = session.get('https://interneturok.ru/school/student-journal/school/' + json.loads(grade.content)['pages']['grade'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I tried a few other ways to do this:

```
j = session.get('https://interneturok.ru/school/student-journal/school/' + json.loads(grade.content)['grade'])

j = session.get('https://interneturok.ru/school/student-journal/school/' + json.loads(grade.content)['pages'][2])
```

But nothing works

Comment: json.loads(grade.content)['pages'] is a list, not a dict. That being said + json.loads(grade.content)['pages'][0]['grade'] should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to retrieve a dictionary item with a list as a value.
`json.loads(grade.content)['pages'][0]['id']` should work.

```
x = json.loads(grade.content)['pages'][0]['id']
j = session.get('https://yoururl.com/' + str(x))
```

Comment: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: call `json.loads()` on its own, convert to `str` then append it to the url for your request. Updated Answer.